# a single method to check if a web element is covered or not

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test. I use `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` to click on web elements, but sometimes they are covered by others and as you know `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` only checks if the element is enabled and visible, so is there any **method** to check if it's covered or not?
by the way I do not want to use codes like:

```
     try{ 
        //click on the element
        }
     catch(Exception e)
         {//it's covered
         }
```

I am looking for something like:

```
blabla.isCovered();
```

because sometimes for example I want to check of a whole window is covered or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use that sort of code, perhaps you should add additional logic to your checkifClickable method than just enabled and visible. Although, I am betting your real question is more along the lines of "How can I check for these conditions prohibiting me from clicking that may be not be apparent from information provided by the DOM".

This is something that makes Automation more difficult than people realize, because you must have detailed knowledge of the site. Is it an element that pops up due to logic or a condition? Then the solution is to close it. Is it a resolution of rendering issue? Then resize window. There is no real cure-all method, you have to tweak the automation logic to suit the site you are working for.

Are you not wanting to click at all and know previously?

If you specifically just don't want to use Try, then implement an assertion that a property changed after you clicked and then set a bool.